# Payfort not work in live serve in latest ios version 13.3.1

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, payfort

The application I am currently working on is throwing an error when redirected to Payfort. This issue is seen on iOS but works properly on android. Additionally the redirection error/issue is not seen on the sandbox but rather observed on the production environment.

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “paymentservices.payfort.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x600001894a20>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9807, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=(

    "<cert(0x7f828303b600) s: paymentservices.payfort.com i: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4>",

    "<cert(0x7f8283185a00) s: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4 i: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5>"

), NSUnderlyingError=0x600002669530 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1202 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerTrust=<SecTrustRef: 0x600001894a20>, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9807, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9807, kCFStreamPropertySSLPeerCertificates=(

    "<cert(0x7f828303b600) s: paymentservices.payfort.com i: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4>",

    "<cert(0x7f8283185a00) s: Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4 i: VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5>"

)}}, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “paymentservices.payfort.com” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://paymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://paymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The certificate for this server is invalid.

Contact the support staff at payfort.com and tell them their Symantec certificate is no longer accepted, due to security concerns. See e.g. https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2018/03/12/distrust-symantec-tls-certificates/